# Rails concatenation in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to use concatenation in rails loop :

I tried :

collection: "Service.active.#{service.type}"

collection: Service.active. + "#{service.type}"

```
<% services.each do |service| %>
   <div class="grid md:col-span-3">
      <%= f.association :services, as: :check_boxes, collection: "Service.active.#{service.type}", input_html: { multiple: false } %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to dynamically invoke a method on Service you can use [`Object#public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.2/Object.html#method-i-public_send). If the method isn't public you can use `send`;

```
Service.active.public_send(service.type)
```